# How do i know the position and length of modified bytes in a file when compared to original file?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have a file lets assume a text file containing text `ABCDEF` and later the file is modified to `ABcDEF`. How would i compare the modified file to the original to know that the file is modified at a position and length of modification done in bytes. The file could be any type, I specified text file as an example.

Comment: By using a [diff algorithm](https://www.google.com/search?q=diff+algorithm).

Comment: will it work for any file types? It should also work with other than text files .

Comment: Different diff algorithms work with different sources. You'll need to choose more than one if you're planning on diff'ing different sorts of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example you can just read files content as strings and compare every char in "for(int=0..." loop, so "i" would be your position.

For more complex changes in file, you have to use some diff algoritm, as Robert says.